# python script taking long time to run

Tags: python

I am writing a script a in python to parse ldap logs and then get the number of searches/binds by each user. I was testing my code on sample files and for smaller files till size of 5-10MB it runs quick and completes within a 1 minute on my local PC. However when i ran the script on a file worth 18M having around 150000 lines in it, it takes around 5 minutes, i want to run this script on file sizes of 100M and maybe be 5-6 files in each run so that means script has to parse almost of 600-700M of data in each run. But i suppose it would take long time to run, so i would need some advise from you guys if my below code can be fine tuned for better performance in terms of execution time.

```
import os,re,datetime
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)
k=defaultdict(list)
start_time=datetime.datetime.now()

fh = open("C:\\Rohit\\ECD Utilization Script - Copy\\logdir\\access","r").read()
pat=re.compile(' BIND REQ .*conn=([\d]*).*dn=(.*")')

srchStr='\n'.join(re.findall(r' SEARCH REQ .*',fh))

bindlist=re.findall(pat,fh)
for entry in bindlist:
    d[entry[-1].split(",")[0]].append(entry[0])

for key in d:
    for con in d[key]:
        count = re.findall(con,srchStr)
        k[key].append((con,len(count)))

#
for key in k:
    print("Number of searches by ",key, " : ",sum([i[1] for i in k[key]]))

for key in d:
    print("No of bind  ",key," = ",len(d[key]))


end_time=datetime.datetime.now()
print("Total time taken - {}".format(end_time-start_time))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with below code.

```
import os,re,datetime
from collections import defaultdict



start_time=datetime.datetime.now()

bind_count=defaultdict(int)
search_conn=defaultdict(int)
bind_conn=defaultdict(str)
j=defaultdict(int)



fh = open("C:\\access","r")
total_searches=0
total_binds=0

for line in fh:
    reg1=re.search(r' BIND REQ .*conn=(\d+).*dn=(.*")', line)
    reg2=re.search(r' SEARCH REQ .*conn=(\d+).*', line)
    if reg1:
        total_binds+=1
        uid,con=reg1.group(2,1)
        bind_count[uid]=bind_count[uid]+1
        bind_conn[con]=uid

    if reg2:
        total_searches+=1
        skey=reg2.group(1)
        search_conn[skey] = search_conn[skey]+1


for conid in search_conn:
    if conid in bind_conn:
        new_key=bind_conn[conid]
        j[new_key]=j[new_key]+search_conn[conid]




for k,v in bind_count.items():
    print(k," = ",v)

print("*"*80)

for k,v in j.items():
    print(k,"-->",v)

fh.close()

del search_conn
del bind_conn

end_time=datetime.datetime.now()
print("Total time taken - {}".format(end_time-start_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing several scans on entire file on the line

`count = re.findall('SEARCH REQ.*'+conid,fh1)`

Avoid this. This is your major problem. Get all conids in a list and iterate on file again and list while your inner loop should consist of conids. Bring it out of outer loop. You will be doing two scans of file.

Also since it is plain Python run with PyPy for faster runs.

You can do this better with a FSM and by spending a bit more RAM. This is a hint and you will have to do your FSM yourself.

Edit 1: This is the version of script I wrote after seeing the log file. Please correct if there is any mistake:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re


def parse(filepath):
        d = {}
        regex1 = re.compile(r'(.*)?BIND\sREQ(.*)uid=(\w+)')
        regex2 = re.compile(r'(.*)?SEARCH\sREQ(.*)uid=(\w+)')
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                for l in f:
                        m = re.search(regex1, l)
                        if m:
                                # print (m.group(3))
                                uid = m.group(3)
                                if uid in d:
                                        d[uid]['bind_count'] += 1
                                else:
                                        d[uid] = {}
                                        d[uid]['bind_count'] = 1
                                        d[uid]['search_count'] = 0
                        m = re.search(regex2, l)
                        if m:
                                # print (m.group(3))
                                uid = m.group(3)
                                if uid in d:
                                        d[uid]['search_count'] += 1
                                else:
                                        d[uid] = {}
                                        d[uid]['search_count'] = 1
                                        d[uid]['bind_count'] = 0

        for k in d:
                print('user id = ' + k, 'Bind count = ' + str(d[k]['bind_count']), 'Search count = ' + str(d[k]['search_count']))


def process_args():
        if sys.argv < 2:
                print('Usage: parse_ldap_log.py log_filepath')
                exit(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
        process_args()
    parse(sys.argv[1])
```

Thank the Gods that it was not complicated enough to warrant an FSM.

Comment: how do better the below code...there is going to be lot of repetitions in below iteration, how can i avoid that.
    for key in d:
        for con in d[key]:
            count = re.findall(con,srchStr)
            k[key].append((con,len(count)))

Comment: Construct FSM. That is the best way.

Comment: Can you guide me in some direction so that i can get started.

Comment: Give me an hour I will suggest an approach, a bit busy in office.

Comment: Sure.. No probs.. I am waiting.. Thank you !!

Comment: can you please suggest some approach.

Comment: I am sorry that I had no internet at home. Your code has changed and by looking at it I cannot figure what are you trying to do i.e. I do not understand your actual problem. You are trying to parse some log to get some information. What is that? Please state your objective of parsing this log. That will help me in giving a useful answer.

Comment: As i mentioned in OP that i am parsing the ldap log file and i want to extract no.of.bind/searches for each user.Getting the binds is fairly easy but the prob is in getting searches as i have to search & count every conid for every bind for every user.That creates a lengthy loop and is increasing the execution alot.

Comment: Sorry that I overlooked that part. My fault. I do not have OpenLDAP log and thus I cannot advice how to do that efficiently. Can you please upload it somewhere a login is not required and I can access the log. Else you can find my email and send in compressed form as I am not aware of SO policy if I can type it here. It is not hard to find my email.

Comment: this is a sample snippet from log file.

Comment: this is a sample snippet from log file.
    `BIND REQ conn=2392151 op=0 msgID=1 version=3 type=SIMPLE dn="uid=test1,ou=users,ou=internal,o=example"
BIND RES conn=2392151 op=0 msgID=1 result=0 authDN="uid=test1,ou=users,ou=internal,o=example" etime=5
SEARCH REQ conn=2392151 op=1 msgID=2 base="uid=test1,ou=users,ou=Internal,o=example" scope=one filter="(o=example)" attrs="ALL"
SEARCH RES conn=2392151 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 nentries=0 etime=1`
There can be multiple searches in a single bind.

Comment: Thanks but it is not really useful for testing the code fully. Can you please compress and send to my email? I am giving my email here: shivshankar.dayal@gmail.com if it violates any policy so be it and if spammers can use it well even then so be it.

Comment: No problem. It is I who offered help and once I have I have to honor my word.

Comment: Just sent you the file.

Comment: As explained in the email you are not parsing the log file correctly hence the solution is not correct,

Comment: The explanation came later. The solution satisfies the original question. Your explanation does not match with what the question originally said.

Comment: Sir you misunderstood original question, i mentioned i wanted i Searches/Binds for every userid, but yuour code is finding the userids in the Search Lines so that is not expected result; however Bind code works fine. Connection IDs in search lines are NOT unique but in BIND lines they are unique..But anyways i really thank you & appreciate your effort & dedication to help me out. THANK YOU !!!

Comment: No I understood the question right and the code does not find only user ids. It finds those lines which have search req/ bind req and user ids. Then puts them in the dictionary and counts those requests. That was exactly the question. Your requirement is different then you need to specify that in such a way that it is clear. I am sorry that I do not have ability to read you have in mind. Just ask anyone here to read your first line of question. But then probably I do not know to read and I am terribly sorry for my mistake for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use **itertools** library instead of so many loops.

Comment: Can you please share some insight on how to do that, i am pretty new to that and have not used itertools till now. Anything to get started would be great help.

Comment: How can i use itertools for to avoid below loop
    `for key in d: for con in d[key]: count = re.findall(con,fh1) k[key].append((con,len(count)))`

Comment: Can you please answer my query in comments above ?

Comment: I would rather appreciate if you can explain your answer,

Answer (score 0):

Your script has a quadratic complexity: for each line in the file you are making a read again to match the log entry.
My suggestion is to read the file only one time and counting the occurrences of the needed entry (the one matching (" BIND REQ ")).

Comment: I have edited my code to some extent but i still can't seem to get rid of this lengthy loop which is the crux of the problem. Can you please suggest a better way to do this. 
    `for key in d:
    for con in d[key]:
        count = re.findall(con,srchStr)
        k[key].append((con,len(count)))`
This loop won't be a problem for small files but in big files the length of list of values of d[key] goes upto 34000 as well, so there is a huge computation

Comment: Hello can you please answer ?

Comment: Here I am. I think it is easier (if I understood your code) to process the input file one line at a time. Search on it the string you need and add the occurrence in a data structure (like a dict keeping the counts).

Comment: Yep it could have been but the requirement is such that 1st i have to search all the conn ids for Bind Reqs & then i have to count the searches made by conn ids.Nw each user can bind multiple times with new conn id and make some searches. Finally i need the stats like UID -> No.of.Searches.